# Matlab- How to find the neighbouring elements of a number in a matrix?

Tags: matlab

For example,  if i have a matrix:

`A=[1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 9 10 11 12]`

and if i select number 6, then it should return a matrix:

`B=[1 2 3; 5 6 7; 9 10 11]`

Comment: What if there are two entries with value `6`?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
    A = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 9 10 11 12];

    num=6;

    [i,j]=find(A==num);
    [len_row,len_col]=size(A);

    cols=(j-1):(j+1);
    cols(cols<1)=[]; %to avoid trying to access values outside matrix
    cols(cols>len_col); %to avoid trying to access values outside matrix

    row=(i-1):(i+1);
    row(row<1)=[]; %to avoid trying to access values outside matrix
    row(row>len_row)=[]; %to avoid trying to access values outside matrix

    new_mat=A(row,cols);
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementing gutzcha's answer as a function with a bit more flexibility:

```
function mat_out = surround(mat_in, number, dis)
  %mat_in: input matrix containing number
  %number: number around which to build the output matrix
  %dis: distance around searched number to crop in_matrix
  %If dis is such that you would need to access values outside
  %matrix, you will end up getting a non square matrix.

  %find first position containing number in matrix:
  [i, j] = find(mat_in==number, 1); 

  [len_row, len_col] = size(mat_in);

  %make sure that I'm not accessing elements outside matrix
  col = max((j-dis), 1):min((j+dis), len_col);
  row = max((i-dis), 1):min((i+dis), len_col);

  mat_out =  mat_in(row, col);
```

then to get what you need, you would do

```
B = surround(A, 6, 1)
```

to get the 3x3 matrix contained in A that has 6 in the center. With this implementation you can also get the 5x5 matrix (if A was bigger) with the same characteristic using the variable `dis`. To avoid collisions, I wrote it so that you will find the first occurrance of `number`, but you can modify it.

Note that if `number` is less than `dis` numbers away from the end of the matrix, like the number 2 in your `A`, you will get the biggest matrix possible:

```
C = surround(A, 2, 1);
```

you will have

```
C = [1, 2, 3; 5, 6, 7]
```

You could modify the code to pad with zeros or whatever you like, so that you get

```
C = [0, 0, 0; 1, 2, 3; 5, 6, 7]
```